# Vuetify 3 V-Stepper Slot Header

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

There are two ways essentially to create a v-stepper in vuetify 3. You either use the properties or the template/slots.

I can't use the properties method as for some reason the transition is messed up, (the transition from one stepper window to the next does not smoothly move left to right, etc.). If you know how to fix this or if this is a bug that will be fixed, that's great too.

Using slots, the transition works fine, however I now need to be able to control the v-stepper header so that I can change the color and change the step to complete. How do I use the v-stepper-header slot in vuetify 3? I haven't been able to find an example on how to do this.

**Slots Version**

```js
<v-stepper 
editable
:items="['Step 1', 'Step 2', 'Step 3']"
non-linear
>            
     <!-- How do I add a template for the header here and control whether its complete or not and color -->
    <template v-slot:item.1>
        <span>Step Window 1</span>
    </template>
    
    <template v-slot:item.2>
        <span>Step Window 2</span>
    </template>

    <template v-slot:item.3>
        <span>Step Window 3</span>
    </template>
</v-stepper>
```

**Property Version**

```js
<v-stepper>
    <v-stepper-header>
    <v-stepper-item
        complete
        editable
        title="Step 1"
        value="1"
    ></v-stepper-item>

    <v-divider></v-divider>

    <v-stepper-item
        complete
        editable
        title="Step 2"
        value="2"
    ></v-stepper-item>

    <v-divider></v-divider>

    <v-stepper-item
        editable
        title="Step 3"
        value="3"
    ></v-stepper-item>
    </v-stepper-header>

    <v-stepper-window>
        <v-stepper-window-item
            value="1"
        >
            <span>Step Window 1</span>
        </v-stepper-window-item>
    </v-stepper-window>

    <v-stepper-window>
        <v-stepper-window-item
            value="2"
        >
            <span>Step Window 2</span>
        </v-stepper-window-item>
    </v-stepper-window>

    <v-stepper-window>
        <v-stepper-window-item
            value="3"
        >
            <span>Step Window 3</span>
        </v-stepper-window-item>
    </v-stepper-window>
</v-stepper>
```

**UPDATE:** As yoduh in the comments pointed out, I had the anatomy of the window messed up in the properties version above. The correct structure for the window is below. I'm going to leave the question though if someone knows how the slot for the header works and can share how to modify the 'completed' value if possible.

**Property Version -- Corrected**

```js
<v-stepper>
  <template v-slot:default="{ prev, next }">
    <v-stepper-header>
    <v-stepper-item
        complete
        editable
        title="Step 1"
        value="1"
    ></v-stepper-item>

    <v-divider></v-divider>

    <v-stepper-item
        complete
        editable
        title="Step 2"
        value="2"
    ></v-stepper-item>

    <v-divider></v-divider>

    <v-stepper-item
        editable
        title="Step 3"
        value="3"
    ></v-stepper-item>
    </v-stepper-header>

    <v-stepper-window>
        <v-stepper-window-item
            value="1"
        >
            <span>Step Window 1</span>
        </v-stepper-window-item>
 
        <v-stepper-window-item
            value="2"
        >
            <span>Step Window 2</span>
        </v-stepper-window-item>
  
        <v-stepper-window-item
            value="3"
        >
            <span>Step Window 3</span>
        </v-stepper-window-item>
    </v-stepper-window>
   <v-stepper-actions
   @click:prev="prev"
   @click:next="next"
   ></v-stepper-actions>
  </template>
</v-stepper>
```

Comment: Did you try to use `v-slot:header-item.1` as shown in doc: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-stepper/#slots ?

Comment: @MarioSantini I saw that in the docs but I haven't because I'm not sure how I would change the hasCompleted property. Is there an example anywhere for this? Ideally the completed property would be based on the status of a v-model or variable.

Comment: The v-stepper with props has smooth transitions when I test, although it does look a little weird with the steps transitioning past each other (one transitions out from left to right while the next transitions right to left).  It's probably because you use multiple `v-stepper-window` elements. You're meant to use one window to wrap **all** window-items.  See the [anatomy](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/steppers/#anatomy) section of the docs

Comment: @yoduh You were absolutely correct. That is why the transition wasn't working correctly!! Thank you! I will leave this up in case someone has the ability to add syntax for the template/slot for the header though and I've updated my question with your fix.

Comment: @supremesector did you also figure out a way to add the v-stepper-actions?

Comment: @JLeon Yes, I updated the property-version corrected above to show it. Basically you need the template v-slot with prev and next and add the v-stepper-actions after the windows.

Answer (score 0):

The `header` slot is a bit confusing, as it does not refer to the whole header, but just the space below the regular header, i.e. below icon, title and subtitle (see [code](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/b9a58adce730d4e1f3536b0e862c97349110ece5/packages/vuetify/src/components/VStepper/VStepperItem.tsx#L176) for exact position). It is used for every header item without specific [`header-item.${item.value}`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-stepper/#slots-header-item) slot ([code](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/aa17f8a7d7552679dd15e944f2b0b4710e2972bc/packages/vuetify/src/components/VStepper/VStepper.tsx#L160)).

As of Vuetify 3.4, the `hasCompleted` prop is not set when using slots. It requires the v-stepper-item to have either the [`completed`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-stepper-item/#props-complete) prop set to true or the [`rules`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-stepper-item/#props-rules) prop set and satisfied, but both are not passed from the v-stepper. I think this is a bug, those props should be set from item objects.

Long story short, for now, you have to use the components directly.